# How to merge two data frames with duplicate columns to concatenate each string value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Having two data frames with the same column names (name, dept). I am trying to merge both data frames if there are any duplicate names and concatenate the dept value to dept column. I want to keep the same amount of rows on the first data frame but only add the value of the second data frame to the first if there is a duplicate.

What I have tried so far is using pandas .merge(on='name') as well as .groupby('name')['dept'].apply(', '.join) but this removes all other rows.

Using merge only shows the values with the duplicates. I would like to return the unchanged list with the same amount of elements, just adding the duplicate value to the column 'dept'

For example:

```py
df1 = df2.merge(on='name')

df1.groupby('name')['dept'].apply(', '.join)

df1:
name      dept

bob       sales
billy     support
jill      accounting
hank      paper


df2:
name      dept

bob       support   
ruby      hr
hank      telesales
billy     accounting


final df:
name      dept
bob       sales, support
billy     support, accounting
jill      accounting
hank      paper, telesales
```

Comment: `pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby('name').dept.apply(', '.join)`.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

## Sure there must be an easier way but in the meantime....

def convert(x):

```
if type(x) == pd.core.series.Series:

    return ','.join(set(x.values))

else:

    return x
```

def merge_them(df1,df2):

```
temp = pd.concat([df1,df2])

index = pd.Index(set(df1.index)|set(df2.index))

return pd.Series(index.map(lambda x: convert(df3['dept'].loc[x])),
                            index = index)
```